# How to use "using" for a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, using

How to use "using" for a function? For example

```
class A;
void f(int);

struct B
{
   using BA = A;
   using Bf = f; ???
};
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
struct B
{
   using BA = A;
   constexpr static auto Bf = f;
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about specifying the type, which can be annoying.

You don't want to declare a non-static variable, otherwise every single copy of your object will be carrying around a function pointer. You also don't want it to be mutable, because then you can reassign it. You also don't want it to be potentially determined at runtime, because then the compiler will have to prove to itself in a given context that a call to `Bf` is really calling `f`, or else pay function indirection costs. The `constexpr` handles these last two points.

Comment: TBH any decent optimizer can spot without help that a simple function pointer is initialized once by a constant expression and not written to later. You get that pretty much for free when doing SSA.

Comment: @MSalters I see statements like this all the time, and they're almost always wrong. On balance, it's very rare that the compiler can inline a function pointer. https://godbolt.org/g/mBMZeF. A static variable is basically a global, and if it's mutable it can change from anywhere at any time. So it's simply not legal to inline it without whole program analysis, which isn't feasible for non-trivial programs. With an instance variable, it may work if the function calling the member function pointer is inlined all the way to where the instance is constructed. That's a big if though.

Comment: The problem with globals (and class statics) is that SSA is virtually impossible, for roughly the reason you've stated. SSA requires not just the visibility of all writes, but also their order. That's why globals are not simple for optimizers. But that's a property of all globals, and not specific to global function pointers.

Comment: @MSalters It seemed to me that your original comment was saying that the constexpr was redundant though. I guess I misunderstood. At any rate, even with a non global, that is a function pointer instance variable, it still will not and actually cannot be optimized out unless the function is inlined. Compilers are very limited across functions that are not inlined which is bound to happen at some point. There is still significant value in constexpr even for an instance variable for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

If `f` is just a function, you could either add a member function pointer:

```
void (*Bf)(int) = f;
```

or just wrap it in a function:

```
void Bf(int i) { f(i); }
```

Probably prefer the latter though, as it avoids adding extra members to `B`.

---

If `f` is a function template, you can't just alias, you'd need to forward to it:

```
template <class... Args>
auto Bf(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(::f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    noexcept(noexcept(::f(std::forward<Args>(args...))))
{
    return ::f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

which is... yeah.

Comment: Any reason why `auto Bf = f;` is not a possibility?

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, every single instance of `B` will have a function pointer, bloating its size. And it can even be reassigned. Since the user takes `using` declaration as their starting point, they clearly are ok with it being the same for all instances and unchangeable.

Comment: @Rakete Because it's ill-formed.

Comment: Since "using" cannot create an alias for a function, I agree that a function pointer is usually a reasonable substitute. Though imo you could improve your answer by clarifying the "name alias" vs. "pointer" difference. Your current wording ("you can’t just alias") makes it sound like they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

[Nir Friedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772071/2805305) is great, but it won't work in case `f` is overloaded.

In C++14 you can have a solution for this with [a generic lambda](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas):

```
struct B {
  using BA = A;
  static constexpr auto BF = [](auto&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
  };
};
```

If that seems a bit complicat that is only because of `std::forward`'s verbosity. I will show it without `std::forward` to make it simpler to grasp (but don't use this as it would fail if `f` has reference types as params):

```
struct B {
  using BA = A;
  static constexpr auto BF = [](auto... args) { return f(args...); };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `A` is just a type while `f` is an actual function. If you want to use `using` to define `Bf` as the *type* of `f`, then use:

```
using Bf = decltype(f);
```

Comment: I'd say this is a comment.